# compiler interaction with OS

Tags: operating-systems, compilers

I want know if compiler interacts with operating system during compilation process.And if yes then which part of compiler interacts with which part of operating system

Comment: There is already a partial answer to this question at http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19464/9550

Comment: You may be interested in this project which puts forward an interesting thesis: "I think of operating systems as being special cases of programming languages. The environment that programs run in is the language and the operating system that implements that environment is the language interpreter." http://losak.sourceforge.net/os_as_compiler.html

Answer (score 2):

Compilation is only a process of converting your code to assembly language. To achieve this task there is no need to interact with OS kernel.

If you also mean linking, interaction with OS is again not a requirement. However, if certain optimizations, or naming conventions and versions are involved, linking might access operating system information. Still, again no code is executed in the kernel level.

Comment: Do assembler also not interact with os in compilation process

Comment: Nope, conversion to assembler is just a conversion from one language to another. (Just like converting Java to C). Executing an assembler code might pass through OS, depending on the OS, but this is not the "compilation" step either.

Linking on the other hand, is building an OS compliant executable and again different than compilation.

Comment: So is assembler specific to a processor ? how does it finds instruction set of processor?

Comment: Yes it is. You write your assembly code (or convert to it) using the instructions provided to you by your vendor, such as Intel. Different CPUs such as Intel or ARM have different instruction sets.